# OpenCL GPU rendering with AMD Carrizo?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl

I just got a new laptop that said it had the AMD Radeon R7 mobile graphics in it. Ubuntu recognizes it as "AMD Carrizo", and Blender 2.79 doesn't have the "OpenCL" GPU rendering option in the System settings. This happens on both Xorg and Wayland

How can I enable OpenCL GPU rendering with AMD Carrizo graphics?

Here are my specs (according to Ubuntu):
[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer please?